# Mercedes E350E Country of manufacture

Tags: mercedes-benz, vin

Does anyone know if the E350E made in USA or Germany?

I found it very confusing since I've encountered with an GLE500E that has VIN starts with W, which indicates that the car was manufactured in Germany, but actually it was manufactured in the USA.

Attached a sticker found on the side of the GLE500E that caused this confusion.

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: That's not the VIN

Comment: Try this : https://www.mbscottsdale.com/blog/mercedes-benz-vin-breakdown/

Comment: @GdD it is the first 3 characters of the VIN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I have been able to find, it seems the first 3 characters of the VIN don't indicate production location. Based on [this](https://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/Vehicle_Identification_Numbers_(VIN_codes)/Mercedes-Benz/VIN_Codes) the first 3 is just the [WMI](https://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/Vehicle_Identification_Numbers_(VIN_codes)/World_Manufacturer_Identifier_(WMI)#World_Manufacturer_Identifier), which still isn't totally standardize. For Mercedes after 2016 the 11th character is used to indicate production location. Keep in mind the more on that first link :

> This chart is not applicable to Mercedes-Benz products produced outside USA or made for markets other than North America. European/World market cars use a different system for encoding VIN numbers.

That said, [according to Mercedes themselves](https://www.mercedesofpalmsprings.com/mercedes-benz-models-made-in-usa/), there are certain models actually made in the USA:

- GLE (Coupe & SUV)
- GLS
- C-Class

So what I can extrapolate from this, is that Mercedes-Benz is the brand, not necessarily the company, and the "WDC" is used to show what corporate entity produced the vehicle. I think this is why they have Daimler-Benz, Daimler-Chrysler and Daimler AG as 3 different codes. It's just part of their [corporate evolution](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daimler_AG).

I haven't been able to find the Euro version chart (at least not a current one), but you may have better luck. I think, with me being in the US, Google is "helping" show "applicable" results and not the correct Euro information.

Comment: Have a check of the link I gave above, it does list 6 or 7 different plants...

Comment: @SolarMike Yeah. Those are the same ones I found, but it doesn't list any plant in the US which I find interesting being that it opened in the '90s. But it seems that if it's made in the US for the US market, then it's one code, and if it's made in the US for another location, it's WDC. A 2017 GLE 63 AMG for sale in Poland I found has "WDC" and the same here is "4jg".